# Convert HTML To Image in .NET Core

Tags: .net-core-2.0, wkhtmltoimage

I want to convert HTML code to Image(png/jpg) on Web Server and then send image link in email in my .NET Core application. I don't want to purchase any third party library like NReco or EVo.

Is there any other way to convert HTML To Image in dotnet core 2.0?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

I use [net-core-html-to-image](https://github.com/andrei-m-code/net-core-html-to-image) library that embeds wkhtmltoimage tool. The library is very simple to use. There is a [nuget](https://www.nuget.org/packages/CoreHtmlToImage/) package:

```
Install-Package CoreHtmlToImage
```

If you want to convert HTML string to image:

```cs
var converter = new HtmlConverter();
var html = "<div><strong>Hello</strong> World!</div>";
var bytes = converter.FromHtmlString(html);
File.WriteAllBytes("image.jpg", bytes);
```

Or for URLs:

```cs
var converter = new HtmlConverter();
var bytes = converter.FromUrl("http://google.com");
File.WriteAllBytes("image.jpg", bytes);
```

Comment: How can i add styles reference in header to reflect the styles in the converting html element?

Comment: something went wrong in input parameter on this line converter.FromHtmlString(html) i think it is not able to copy exe file is there any solution for this?

Comment: doesn't appear to support javascript/jquery or css unfortunately

Comment: the image converted display different, how can it be fixed?

Comment: Only works on windows. Shame.

Comment: Why it is not working on Linux machine, throwing the following exception:  "The type initializer for 'CoreHtmlToImage.HtmlConverter' threw an exception"  An error occurred trying to start process '/bin/bash' with working directory '/bin/'. No such file or directory

Answer (score 2):

I know this is old but I wanted to save some from headaches if you come across it. The wkhtmltopdf.exe file that this uses, uses an older rendering engine. I had to go all the way back to bootstrap v2 to make it render correctly.

Answer (score 0):

There are number of free libraries on web to convert HTML to image/PDF/other formats.

I prefer TuesPechkin dll to export to image/pdf.

For image you need to use wkhtmltoimage dll. You can go through below links:
https://wkhtmltopdf.org/

Below is the Github link. You can find more details here:
https://github.com/tuespetre/TuesPechkin

Answer (score 0):

Sharing you the solution, which might helps to others

I used wkhtmltopdf.exe and it worked.

Following post helped me

https://beeming.net/just-coding/2017/5/converting-html-to-pdf-using-c-and-magic