# Screenshot from a page in localhost

Tags: c#, asp.net, vb.net

I've tried using of `webBrowser` approach to taking screenshot. It is available from [this link](https://forums.asp.net/post/6005029.aspx).

But it captures screenshot from an online webpage. I want to take screenshot from another page of my localhost website.

Is there any possibility to capture a screenshot from another page of my localhost application.

I want to use the file as a thumbnail in my application.

Comment: I am a little bit confused about your need, converting html to image can solve your problem ? see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50138052/convert-html-to-image-in-net-core-2-0

Comment: What do you mean when you say it captures a different page?

Comment: @derloopkat I mean it only works for online websites. But I want to capture a screenshot from my localhost website

Comment: @G.Sofien Thank you for your reply. Actually I need to capture a screenshot from a localhost website to use it as a thumbnail in a list. I'm using .net framework not .net core

Comment: Use the Snipping Tool in Windows when the page is displayed.